# How can I invoke function jquery with ashx handler?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, handler, invoke

I'd like to know how can I invoke a function in an aspx handler(.ashx).

This is what I've tried:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) ...

context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
context.Response.Write("<script>$('#showAlert').show();</script>");
```

but this does nothing, I'd like to know if is it possible and if it is how can I do it.

I can refer that the aler is written in a web user control.

//THIS IS USED TO CALL THE HANDLER

```
$("#saveChanges").click(function () {
        $("#gif").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../handlers/adminSaveResults.ashx?pinAntigo=" + $("#pin").val() + "&pinNovo=" + $("#pinNovo").val() + "&passAntiga=" + $("#old").val() + "&passNova=" + $("#newP").val() + "",
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#gif").hide();
            },
            error: function (data) { /*alert("ERRO: " + data.status);*/ $("#gif").hide(); },
            timeout: 15000
        });
    }
  );
```

**Regards**

Comment: Just curious as to why you want to do this, as opposed to just using jQuery in the page via a selector event (i.e. click event)?

Comment: this is to use after doing some events, then showes the alert

Comment: How are you calling this?  You probably just need to remove the script tags and send it back as plain text.  (This obviously depends a great deal on factors we don't currently have information about.)  Can you post the calling script?

Comment: Post more of your code, specifically the context(s) that call this handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, it should be something like this:

Server:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) ...    
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
context.Response.Write("{"ok": 1 }");
```

And here is the js:

```
$("#saveChanges").click(function () {
        $("#gif").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../handlers/adminSaveResults.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            data: {pinAntigo: $("#pin").val(),
                   pinNovo: $("#pinNovo").val(),
                   passAntiga: $("#old").val(),
                   passNova: $("#newP").val() } ,
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            if(data.ok){
                {
                    $('#showAlert').show();
                }     
                $("#gif").hide();
            },
            error: function (data) { /*alert("ERRO: " + data.status);*/ $("#gif").hide(); },
            timeout: 15000
        });
    }
  );
```